# Signed Transaction on Ropsten undepriced

Tags: transactions, dapps, ethereumjs

I am trying to send raw transaction data for a contract from a React frontend to a Node backend, sign it, then send it to the Ropsten network. However I am always getting the error "Error: Returned error: transaction underpriced" no matter what I set the gas too. Most of the answers I have found have been in relation to "replacement transaction underpriced" but that doesn't apply here. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code so far:

Front End

```
const publicAddress = accounts[0];

const agraContract = new web3.eth.Contract(config.ABI, 'an address');

var requestEncodedABI = agraContract.methods.requestAGRA(publicAddress).encodeABI();
const nonce = await web3.eth.getTransactionCount('an address');

var rawRequestTx = {
    nonce: nonce,
    to: 'an address',
    gasPrice: web3.eth.gasPrice,
    gasLimit: web3.eth.getBlock('latest').gasLimit,
    data: requestEncodedABI,
    chainId: 3
}

fetch('/api/transactions/signtx', {
    body: JSON.stringify(rawRequestTx),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
})
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Here is the backend

```
let web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider(process.env.INFURA_API_KEY));

export const sign = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const rawTx = req.body;
    const common = new Common({ chain: Chain.Ropsten });
    var tx = Transaction.fromTxData(rawTx, { common });
    var privateKey = Buffer.from(process.env.ADMIN_PRIV_KEY, 'hex');
    const signedTx = tx.sign(privateKey);
    var serializedTx = signedTx.serialize();
    return web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'))
        .on('receipt', () => {
            console.log('success');
            res.json('success');
        }).catch(next);
};
```